# Scroll offset doesnt work same with on down scroll as on top scroll

Tags: jquery, html

i have navigation in wordpress where every link leads to section inside of page. sections goes like

```
<section id="1">lorem ipsum dolor sit</section>
<section id="2">lorem ipsum dolor sit</section>
<section id="3">lorem ipsum dolor sit</section>
```

and i have a js function to add smooth scroll on click that leads to those sections

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
  // adjust scroll position on page load if *-section hash present
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var target = null;
    if (window.location.hash.indexOf('-section') > 0) {
      target = window.location.hash.substr(0, window.location.hash.indexOf('-section'));
    }
    else if (jQuery(window.location.hash).hasClass('section')) {
      target = window.location.hash;
    }
    if (target) {
      jQuery.smoothScroll({
        scrollTarget: jQuery(target),
        offset: -50,
        afterScroll: function() {
          window.location.hash = target + '-section';
        },
      });
    }
  }

});
```

and when scroll goes down it works fine but when it goes up he goes a little higher then it should. When i remove offset -50px, when scroll goes down it cut off section a little but when it goes up it goes perfectly. 
When i click first time on link it goes slightly higher then section but when i click on that same link again it goes little lower just berfect as it should be.
Can someone help me what am i doing wrong?